# Create a key map for all paths in a recursive/nested object array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, recursion, nested

I have an n levels deep nested array of tag objects with title and ID. What I'm trying to create is a an object with IDs as keys and values being an array describing the title-path to that ID.

I'm no master at recursion so my attempt below doesn't exactly provide the result I need.

Here's the original nested tag array:

```
const tags = [
  {
    title: 'Wood',
    id: 'dkgkeixn',
    tags: [
      {
        title: 'Material',
        id: 'ewyherer'
      },
      {
        title: 'Construction',
        id: 'cchtfyjf'
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    title: 'Steel',
    id: 'drftgycs',
    tags: [
      {
        title: 'Surface',
        id: 'sfkstewc',
        tags: [
          {
            title: 'Polished',
            id: 'vbraurff'
          },
          {
            title: 'Coated',
            id: 'sdusfgsf'
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        title: 'Quality',
        id: 'zsasyewe'
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

The output I'm trying to get is this:

```
{
  'dkgkeixn': ['Wood'],
  'ewyherer': ['Wood', 'Material'],
  'cchtfyjf': ['Wood', 'Construction'],
  'drftgycs': ['Steel'],
  'sfkstewc': ['Steel', 'Surface'],
  'vbraurff': ['Steel', 'Surface', 'Polished'],
  'sdusfgsf': ['Steel', 'Surface', 'Coated'],
  'zsasyewe': ['Steel', 'Quality']
}
```

So I'm building this recursive function which is almost doing it's job, but I keep getting the wrong paths in my flat/key map:

```
function flatMap(tag, acc, pathBefore) {
  if (!acc[tag.id]) acc[tag.id] = [...pathBefore];
  acc[tag.id].push(tag.title);

  if (tag.tags) {
    pathBefore.push(tag.title)
    tag.tags.forEach(el => flatMap(el, acc, pathBefore))
  }
  return acc
}

const keyMap = flatMap({ title: 'Root', id: 'root', tags}, {}, []);
console.log("keyMap", keyMap)
```

I'm trying to get the path until a tag with no tags and then set that path as value for the ID and then push the items 'own' title. But somehow the paths get messed up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this, `makePaths` arguments are `tags`, `res`ult object and `prefix`ed titles.

```js
const makePaths = (tags, res = {}, prefix = []) => {
  tags.forEach(tag => {
    const values = [...prefix, tag.title];
    Object.assign(res, { [tag.id]: values });
    if (tag.tags) {
      makePaths(tag.tags, res, values);
    }
  });
  return res;
};

const tags = [
  {
    title: "Wood",
    id: "dkgkeixn",
    tags: [
      {
        title: "Material",
        id: "ewyherer"
      },
      {
        title: "Construction",
        id: "cchtfyjf"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    title: "Steel",
    id: "drftgycs",
    tags: [
      {
        title: "Surface",
        id: "sfkstewc",
        tags: [
          {
            title: "Polished",
            id: "vbraurff"
          },
          {
            title: "Coated",
            id: "sdusfgsf"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        title: "Quality",
        id: "zsasyewe"
      }
    ]
  }
];

console.log(makePaths(tags));
```